# How to debug javascript in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, windows

We are trying to build a Windows 8 native application using JavaScript. We are using jQuery to dynamically load the javascripts files, and all the javascript files are stored inside of the app. When I try to debug the javascript, the breakpoint can't hit, saying "The breakpoint will not currently be hit....", but in the Solution Explorer, there is a Script Documents project, there is a file called "script block", which contains all the javascripts which are loaded from jQuery. I can debug from there after I disable the "Enable Just My Code", but it's difficult to find the right place to put breakpoint, since this file is huge...

Actually all the javascript files are having sourcemap attribute, for example: //# sourceURL=ms-appx://d664ef20-6ac8-11e4-ab78-2f4dc8b50d53/www/resources/abc.js

It is working fine with all the browsers, IE, Safari, Firefox and Chrome. But Visual Studio seems not be able to recognize them.

Anyone who has the same issue?

Regards,
Xiaojun

Comment: How are you loading the JavaScript via jQuery? Does it work as expected if you include them as script files normally?

Comment: No, they are loaded via ajax call even though they are at local disk, and then use window.eval to execute them.

Comment: If you try inserting a "debugger;" keyword where you would normally set a breakpoint, does execution pause when it hits the keyword?

Comment: Yes, "debugger" works. But our project has a lot of JS files, I can't insert debugger at anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are doing this, which evals the contents as a string, causing the string to be added to the "eval code" file under Script Documents. Note, you can still set breakpoints, you just have to do it from the "eval code" document.

```
// eval via AJAX -- adds to the "eval code" document
$.ajax("./js/fileToAdd.js").done(function (data) {
    window.eval(data);
});
```

If you load the file via a script tag, the script file is loaded separately and breakpoints bind as expected because the contents are tied to the file and not a string. Here's how:

```
// Add <script> tag to head -- Causes script file to be loaded/displayed individually
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src =  "./js/fileToAdd.js"
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for you help.If we use script to load the file, the scrip won't be executed immediately. <p>abc</p>

Comment: This will still delay loading it to whenever the block of code runs. You could wrap that second block of code in a function (perhaps with a filename parameter) and then call it when you wanted the code to load.

Comment: I know that, we have a huge mount of js files which written in this way, can't afford to change this.

Comment: Ah. Would support for `//# sourceURL="path/to/file.js"` fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, if Visual Studio can support sourceURL, that would be great. And we can debug then.

Comment: I posted the feedback to [the Visual Studio User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6737362-support-sourceurl-in-in-the-js-debugger).